# The precision of the number

Tags: machine-precision, number-representation

I have problem in *Mathematica* with unnecessary rounding which is caused by high precision.
For example I have value `a = 2.052685846*10^-1865`, when I make `b = 1 - a` the result is `b == 1.`
What can I do to have a better precision, without rounding?

Comment: Works for me, but I'm on 9.0.1. Don't imagine any major differences here between versions - are your examples *exactly* what you're using?

Comment: @rasher Yes, it is EXACTLY the same. So as you can see, there must be a difference. Or maybe I can change seetings to have better precision?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `b = 1. - a`? The decimal point after the 1 makes all the difference.

Comment: Considering Mr.Wizard's answer, I don't think this question should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me on *Mathematica 8.0.*
however, you can try using `N`  to have the value number with the number of significant digits as you like:

```
b = N[ 1-a, 2000]
```

$2000$ digits after the decimal point in this case *Mathematica* does not perform rounding to $1$.

Comment: @Ziva `N[ 1-a, 2000]` yields the same result as `1 - a` for me (V9.0.1, 8.0.4, 7.0.0).  I don't get 2000 digitsl I get 1880 plus 27 insignificant digits.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that there may be an issue of [`$MaxMachineNumber`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24MaxMachineNumber.html) in play here.  On my machine `$MaxMachineNumber` is `1.79769*10^308` therefore:

```
MachineNumberQ[a = 2.052685846*10^-1865]

Precision[1 - a]
```

> ```
> False
>
> 1880.64
> ```

This means that `1 - a` is done with arbitrary precision arithmetic and all digits are displayed.  However if a smaller exponent is used such that `a` is machine size only machine precision arithmetic will be used, and the result is `1.`:

```
MachineNumberQ[a = 2.052685846*10^-186]  (* note -186 *)

1 - a

Precision @ %
```

> ```
> True
>
> 1.
>
> MachinePrecision
> ```