# Number precision in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, version-7, machine-precision

I have list with elements:

```
l = {1.000000000*10^-2076, 2.052685846*10^-1865, 7.337942425*10^-1741, 
6.994455902*10^-1652, 2.007623567*10^-1582, 2.482890841*10^-1525, 
8.737178026*10^-1477, 1.673592426*10^-1434, 5.183426213*10^-1397, 
2.634095605*10^-1363}
```

I want to make a list l2, where each element i is equal to 1 - l[[i]]. So I made:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[l], i++, a = l[[i]]; b = 1 - a; 
  l2 = AppendTo[l2, b]];
```

But as a result I have :

```
l2 = {1.000000000, 1.000000000, 1.000000000, 1.000000000, 1.000000000, 
1.000000000, 1.000000000, 1.000000000, 1.000000000, 1.000000000}
```

What is wrong, because if I will take the first element from l

```
a = 1.000000000*10^-2076 
b = 1 - a = 0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999979473141540
```

what is ok. How can I convert l to l2, to have the good precision?

Comment: `N[l2,2000]`, e.g. You have asked very similar questions *several* times - have you bothered to read the documentation and post links provided in the answers to your other questions? In fact, you asked a nearly identical question (here)[http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44428/the-precision-of-the-number]

Comment: @rasher I posted one similar question. But notice the difference. That there was just question about one value, which WASN'T in a list, what makes a big difference. Because making N[l2,2000] doesn't helps, whereas N[a,2000] outside the list works fine. So I think I can be posted in separate question, because in the previous post is no answer for that, so I don't understand why you flag it.

Comment: This appears to be again an idiosyncrasy of earlier versions of *Mathematica*, as per the answers to your earlier questions. The result comes out in v9.0.1 fine, with no hand-waving or use of `N[]`. Try `N[#,2000]/@l2` and report back. I flagged because the documentation links, other answer links, and the answers themselves to your previous precision queries have I believe given you all the tools to get the result you want, and to understand what/why/where of precision.